# Django admin list_filter ForeignKey with large related table

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User')
```

And this ModelAdmin:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'user']
    list_filter = ['user']
```

Filtering works well, but I faced with such problem. In my case `users.User` table is very big, so when Django is rendering `PostAdmin` page, it takes too many time to render all users.

So I am wondering if it is possible to use Django Admin filter with ForeignKey without rendering all related objects, something like `raw_id_fields` widget for filters?

Comment: You are looking for [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thank for reply. But I need to have opportunity
to select any user I want in filter, without limitation, so `limit_choices_to` is not the solution in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-salmonella looks like this will provide a raw id filter for any FK.

`# pip install django-salmonella`

```
from salmonella.admin import SalmonellaMixin
from salmonella.filters import SalmonellaFilter

class UserProfileAdmin(SalmonellaMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_filter = (
       ('salmonella_fk', SalmonellaFilter),
   )
```

You can also clean up the styling for `grapelli` https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2015/02/06/pretty-raw_id_fields-django-salmonella-and-django-grappelli/

in `app/templates/salmonella/admin/widgets/salmonella_field.html`

```
{{ hidden_input }}
<a onclick="return showRelatedObjectLookupPopup(this);" id="lookup_id_{{ name }}" data-name="{{ name }}" data-app="{{ app_name }}" data-model="{{ model_name }}" class="related-lookup" href="{{ related_url }}{{ url }}"><img width="16" height="16" alt="Consultazione" src="/static/admin/img/selector-search.gif"></a>
<a data-name="developers" data-app="{{ app_name }}" data-model="{{ model_name }}" class="salmonella-clear-field"></a>
<span class="salmonella_label" id="{{ name }}_salmonella_label"></span>
```

and `app/templates/salmonella/multi_label.html`

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <a href="{{ object.1 }}" >{{ object.0 }}</a>{% if not forloop.last %} {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

AND a style sheet:

```
.salmonella-clear-field {
    background-image: url("/static/grappelli/images/icons/related-remove.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.salmonella_label {
    position: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
.salmonella_label a {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I was able to figure out is customize Filter with raw_id_field widget.

Create template `user_filter.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/forms.css' %}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">var go_from_select = function(opt) { window.location = window.location.pathname + opt };</script>
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
<div class="admin-filter-user" style="margin-left:15px">
    <input type="text" style="display:inline-block;" name="{{title}}" value="{{ request.GET.user__id__exact }}" id="id_{{title}}" class="vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField"/>
    <a href="{% url 'admin:users_user_changelist' %}" class="related-lookup" style="display:inline-block;" id="lookup_id_{{title}}" title="Lookup"></a>
    <input type="button" onclick="go_from_select('?user__id__exact='+id_user.value)" value="Filter" />
    <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; margin-left:7px" onclick="go_from_select('')">clear</a>
</div>
```

Create new Filter class and override default template:

```
class UserFilter(admin.RelatedFieldListFilter):
    """Raw_id_filter for user field"""
    template = 'admin/user_filter.html'
```

Set `UserFilter` as filter class for user field in `ModelAdmin`:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'user']
    list_filter = [('user', UserFilter)]
```

This will set raw_id_field widget for `user` filter and increase page rendering performance.